# Difference between "distribution" & "arrangement".

Tags: combinatorics, terminology

Number of ways of **Arrangement** of $n$ different things into $r$ different groups is $$n!\binom{n - 1}{r - 1}$$.

Number of ways of **distribution** of $n$ different things into $r$ different groups is the number of onto functions ie. $$\sum_{k = 0}^r (-1)^r (r - k)^n$$.

Apart from the formula, what are the differences between the two- **distribution** & **arrangement**?

Comment: basically do you want to know difference between permutation and combination?

Comment: Yes, I do know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The terms *distribution* and *arrangement* are being used fairly informally here; in this context they don’t have precise technical definitions. Here’s one way to see the difference between what

$$\sum_{k=0}^r(-1)^r(r-k)^n\tag{1}$$

and

$$n!\binom{n-1}{r-1}\tag{2}$$

are counting. As you say, $(1)$ is the number of functions from $[n]$ onto $[r]$. In other words, if I have balls numbered $1$ through $n$ and containers numbered $1$ through $r$, $(1)$ is the number of ways to distribute the $n$ balls amongst the $r$ containers so that each container gets at least one ball.

$(2)$, on the other hand, is the number of ways to line up the numbered balls and then put $r-1$ dividers into the lineup, thereby dividing the balls into $r$ segments, in such a way that each segment is non-empty. If I now dump the balls in the first segment into container $1$, the balls in the second segment into container $2$, and so on, I’ll have one of the distributions counted by $(1)$. Notice, though, that I can change the order of the balls within any segment without changing the distribution that I get. In other words, many different arrangements counted by $(2)$ correspond to the same distribution counted by $(1)$.

To turn it around, suppose that I distribute the balls amongst the containers as in the first paragraph. Now I take the balls out of container $1$ and line them up; if there are $n_1$ balls in container $1$, I can do this in $n_1!$ different ways. Then I do the same with the balls in container $2$, lining them up after the ones from container $1$, with a divider between the two groups. If there are $n_2$ balls in container $2$, I can do this in $n_2!$ ways. I can keep going, and when I’m done, I’ll have a permutation of the $n$ balls, with $r-1$ dividers breaking it into non-empty segments. And if container $k$ has $n_k!$ balls (for $k=1,\ldots,r$), then I can make $n_1!n_2!\ldots n_r!$ different arrangements of balls and dividers from that one distribution of balls amongst containers.